# Hero section under transparent navigational menu

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to search for a solution but I couldn't find any yet.
I would like to make a transparent navigational menu bar with a hero section just like in this website here https://paragonmigration.com/

I'm having trouble with the image part where the navigation menu overlapses it.

This is what I have done so far with html:

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%; /* fixes white space on the right side */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* fixes white space on the right side */
    }
    
    h4 {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    /*#top-header {
         height: 39px;
         background-color: #36404a;
         color: #fff;
        line-height: 39px;
        padding-left: 50px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }*/
    
    .top-header {
        display: flex;
        background-color: #36404a;
        color: #fff;
        height: 39px;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .top-header > div {
        margin: 0 15px;
    }
    
    .top-header > div > i {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .top-header-address {
        padding-left: 50px; 
    }
    
    .top-header-email {
        flex: 2;
    }
    
    .top-header-facebook {
        flex-basis: 2em;
    }
    
    .top-header-facebook a {
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .top-header-book {
        display: flex; /* in order to center the elements inside */
        background-color: #fa0505;
        flex-basis: 251px;
        height: 100%; /* in order to entirely stretch and fill to the parent element's* height */
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    /* remove the right margin for the last div */
    .top-header div:nth-last-child(1) { 
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .top-header-book a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:  #fff;
        margin-right: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    /*
    #site-header-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    */
    
    
    .nav-menu {
        display: flex;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    /* add sticky functionality to navigation menu */
    .sticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #36404a;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .sticky.nav-menu ul li a {
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .logo img {
        height: 75px;
        width: 156px;
    }
    
    .nav-menu ul {
        display: flex;
        flex: 4;
        /*height:  100%;*/
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-menu ul > li {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    
    .nav-menu ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
    }
    
    .have-questions {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .message-icon i {
        color: red;
    }
    
    .questions {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 10px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
    
    #slider {
        position: relative;
        top: -150px;
        padding: 0;
        background: url('../assets/images/slide.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
       /* background-size: cover;*/
        height: 750px;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
   <div id="site-header-menu">
             
        <div class="container top-header">
            
            <div class="top-header-address">
               <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                Address: 2903, Single Business Tower, Dubai
            </div>
            
            <div class="top-header-email">
                <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                Email Address: info@paragonmigration.com
            </div>
            
            <div class="top-header-facebook">
                <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="top-header-book">
               
                <a href="#">Book A Consultation</a>
                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i>        
            </div>
            
        </div><!-- #site-header-menu -->
    
        <div class="nav-menu" id="nav-menu">
          <div class="logo"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CANADA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">POLAND</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AUSTRALIA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NEW ZEALAND</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">UK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <div class="have-questions">
                <div class="message-icon"><i class="far fa-comment-alt fa-3x"></i></div>
                <div class="questions">
                    <div>Have any Questions?</div>
                    <div>04 303 3000</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div><!-- .nav-menu -->  
    
    </div><!-- site-header-menu -->
          <div id="slider">
              <p id="welcome">WELCOME TO PARAGON</p>
              <p id="migration">Migration and Visa</p>
              <p id="consultants"><em>Consultants</em></p>
              <a href="#">LEARN MORE > </a>
          </div><!-- #slider -->
```